# How can i align a picture with css?

Tags: html, css, layout, bootstrap-4, css-float

i was trying to do [this](https://www.sololearn.com/post/17470/?ref=app) but i couldn't find a way to do it or an attribute. Could anyone help me do that ?
my code is below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--Bootstrap-->
<meta name="viewport"        content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Decleration-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body style="height: px"> 
<!--Content-->
<!--navbar-fixed-top (fix that)-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Directory 41</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<!--first tab-->
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Topics<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Computer Building</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Cryptocurrencies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hacking</a><li>
    <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Troubleshooting</ a></li>
</ul>       
<!--second tab-->
  <li class="dropdown">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-    toggle="dropdown" href="#">Books<span class="caret"></ span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">CWNA Guide to Wireless LANs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Learn CCNA</a></li>
</ul>
<!--Third Tab-->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Definitions<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Computer Building</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cryptocurrencies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hacking</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Troubleshooting</a></li>
</ul>        
<!--Fourth Tab-->
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About Us<span class="caret"></span>       
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Survey</a></li>
 </ul>
 </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 <!--End of Nav Bar-->
 <!--Beggining of Content-->
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque gravida, lectus vitae gravida pharetra, arcu mi commodo orci, non tempus ex diam sit amet lorem. Nulla eros tortor, dictum nec lacus mattis, interdum pharetra leo. Phasellus lobortis nulla id ex tristique iaculis. Donec nec facilisis mi. Vestibulum at est elementum, laoreet eros sit amet, mollis dolor. Suspendisse sit amet varius mauris.</p>
<!--Gallery(Books)-->

<!--first gallery-->
<div class="gallery">
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<img src="image" alt="" height="200" width="150"></a>
<div class="desc">Desc goes here</div></div>

<!--second gallery-->
<div class="gallery2">
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<img src="image" alt="#" height="200" width="150"></a>
<div class="desc">Desc goes here</div></div>
</body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
/*content*/
body {
  background-color: light gray;
}
/*p {
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 10px;
 background-color: black;
 color: yellow;
}*/

/*gallery*/
.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
}
.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}
.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*gallery 2*/
.gallery2 {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
}
</style>
```

and sorry for left out code if anyone can fix that thx because its a long time to do 4 spaces on each line on mobile and dont really know how to add code so im reallyt sorry. thx for any help

also i left out the image on img src because it didnt let me put it

Comment: Link goes to a 404 page.

Comment: here is a new hopefully working link https://code.sololearn.com/Wqby20H9rKvj

Comment: I believe you want to look at this section of bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#images

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--Bootstrap-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Decleration-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>

<style type="text/css">
  /*content*/
  body {
    background-color: light gray;
  }
  /*p {
   padding: 10px;
   margin: 10px;
   background-color: black;
   color: yellow;
  }*/

  /*gallery*/
  .gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: left;
    width: 170px;
  }
  .gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
  }
  .gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  /*gallery 2*/
  .gallery2 {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    float: right;
    width: 180px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%"> 
<!--Content-->
<!--navbar-fixed-top (fix that)-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Directory 41</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<!--first tab-->
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Topics<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Computer Building</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Cryptocurrencies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hacking</a><li>
          <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Troubleshooting</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </li>


<!--second tab-->
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Books<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">CWNA Guide to Wireless LANs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Learn CCNA</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


<!--Third Tab-->
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Definitions<span class="caret"></span></a>    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Computer Building</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cryptocurrencies</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Hacking</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programming</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Troubleshooting</a></li>
  </ul>   </li>


<!--Fourth Tab-->
  <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Survey</a></li>
   </ul></li>


 </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Sign Up</a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Login</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 <!--End of Nav Bar-->
 <!--Beggining of Content-->
 <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque gravida, lectus vitae gravida pharetra, arcu mi commodo orci, non tempus ex diam sit amet lorem. Nulla eros tortor, dictum nec lacus mattis, interdum pharetra leo. Phasellus lobortis nulla id ex tristique iaculis. Donec nec facilisis mi. Vestibulum at est elementum, laoreet eros sit amet, mollis dolor. Suspendisse sit amet varius mauris.</p>
<!--Gallery(Books)-->

<!--first gallery-->
<div class="gallery">
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<img src="image" alt="" height="200" width="150"></a>
<div class="desc">Desc goes here</div></div>

<!--second gallery-->
<div class="gallery2">
<a target="_blank" href="#">
<img src="image" alt="#" height="200" width="150"></a>
<div class="desc">Desc goes here</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would like to move that image to the top, Idk if it doesn't so that maybe because I'm on mobile, big if there is a way pls let me know, hope i redefined it

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you want, but I'm not sure how it will behave having the image nested in the anchor tag. For reference see the bootstrap documentation on image topped cards: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/card/#images

```
<div class="gallery card">
    <a target="_blank" href="#">
        <img src="image" alt="" height="200" width="150" class="card-img-top">
    </a>
    <div class="desc card-body">
        <p class="card-text">Desc goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```